# What is the faster alternative for nested while loops which I am using for extracting elements from a List?

Tags: performance, python-2.7, nested-loops

I am using code mentioned below to extract elements from `List2` and create A new list Coordinates. I am looking for better ways to make it faster

```
while m<(Length1 - 4) :

    j = 0

    while j<3 :

        l = 0

        while l<3 :

            Coordinates[i]= List2[m]
            l = l+1
            m = m+1
            i = i+1


        m = m+1
        j = j+1

    m = m+9
```

Comment: I think your question could do with some clarification. But for an answer in one word: numpy

Comment: The list2 contains both character strings and number strings. Will numpy be useful?

Comment: yes. For starters, you can use numpy to (virtually) eliminate the cost of looping, and also increase expressiveness of said loops. If your strings are fixed length, you will also get a large speedup in the string handling. If not, you can still use a numpy array of type object to take care of your strings

Comment: But for the cleanest numpy solution, your problem needs a little more context I think. Given the right knowledge about your problem, you could express Coordinates as a view on List2, in O(1) time, and a single line of code.

Comment: And by 'right knowledge', I mean a piece of standalone code that will run